# Utilising composers asset-installer-paths not working

Tags: yii, composer-php, yii2

I'm trying to install a certain package in composer into a certain path, the package name is `cyphix333/nbbc` and normally it would be installed into `vendor/cyphix333/nbbc` however I wanted to install it into `vendor/nbbc` so I tried this in the main project `composer.json`

```
"require": {
    //......
    "cyphix333/nbbc": "dev-master"
},

"extra": {
    "asset-installer-paths": {
        //.....
        "cyphix333/nbbc": "vendor/nbbc"
    }
}
```

However it didn't work, it still installed into `vendor/cyphix333/nbbc`.

**Edit:** ...and here is the full data from the `extra` part, which comes from my php framework `yii2`:

```
"extra": {
    "yii\\composer\\Installer::postCreateProject": {
        "setPermission": [
            {
                "runtime": "0777",
                "web/assets": "0777",
                "yii": "0755"
            }
        ],
        "generateCookieValidationKey": [
            "config/web.php"
        ]
    },
    "asset-installer-paths": {
        "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
        "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower",
        "cyphix333/nbbc": "vendor/nbbc"
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. `asset-installer-paths` = Composer plugin `fxp/composer-asset-plugin`**

The [`asset-installer-paths` directive](https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin/blob/1.0/Resources/doc/index.md#define-a-custom-directory-for-the-assets-installation) belongs to the Composer plugin `fxp/composer-asset-plugin`.
The plugin is required, for this directive to work. But you are not requiring it in your project repo or globally.

[Docu - Installation](https://github.com/francoispluchino/composer-asset-plugin/blob/1.0/Resources/doc/index.md#installation)

```
composer require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.0"
```

or

```
composer global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.0"
```

**2. Is `cyphix333/nbbc` a Bower or NPM asset?**

No.

**3. What am I doing wrong here?**

You think, that you can use `asset-installer-paths` directive to move your package to a specific folder. You can't. Because your repo is not an Bower or NPM asset.

**4. How can i move my package from `vendor/cyphix333/nbbc` to `vendor/nbbc`?**

Stop trying that. It's wasted time. Why? Composer has an Autoloader and he does the mapping from classname to filename. Please do not care about the path, just define an autloading strategy (files or classmap) and start using your class.

If you really need to copy stuff, you might use the `scripts` section of your composer.json.
https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md

Comment: Hmmmmm weird. My main PHP framework is `Yii2` and it was already using `asset-installer-paths` and I just added an extra line to it. I will update my question with the full `extra` part.